# Maven failsafe plugin integration-test passes but verify fails with error

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a project with a Maven continuous build in Jenkins. When the `maven-failsafe-plugin:integration-test` phase runs, it says there are 0 failures and 0 errors.  However, when the `maven-failsafe-plugin:verify` runs, it says "[ERROR] There are test failures."  To wit:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:integration-test (default) @ my-container ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /tmp/workspace/.../my-container/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyConfigIT
Apr 27, 2016 4:57:22 PM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
INFO: Trying to find master from available Sentinels...
Apr 27, 2016 4:57:22 PM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
INFO: Redis master running at 127.0.0.1:6379, starting Sentinel listeners...
Apr 27, 2016 4:57:22 PM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initPool
INFO: Created JedisPool to master at 127.0.0.1:6379

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:verify (default) @ my-container ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /tmp/workspace/.../my-container/target/failsafe-reports
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

This is doubly bizarre because there is actually only *one* test in `MyConfigIT`. Why does it say it ran 2?

Furthermore, when I `ls` the report directory, the report for the failing test has 0 bytes:

```
+ ls -al /tmp/workspace/.../target/failsafe-reports

-rw-rw-r--.  1 xoom xoom    0 Apr 29 11:23 com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyConfigIT.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run it with -X to get more details maybe?

Comment: How are you calling Maven in Jenkins?